# How much storage I need for this CCTV system and what capacity it has?

Tags: hard-drive, cctv, surveillance, home-surveillance

I'm planning to buy [DS-7604NI-E1 / 4p](http://www.hikvision.com/us/Products_1_10649_i8678.html).

In the website it says that it can handle

> "Up to 4TB for each disk"

So does that mean that I can have 10 4TB attached to this NVR? I searched Google regarding this and it showed this picture. So thats why I'm confused on where I will install the HDD if the space is so small.

[NVR HD installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R4bK.jpg)

Or can I buy something like a HDD docking station and attach this to the NVR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DVR in the picture is different to the one in the link. The one in the link is specced to take a single internal drive with a maximum capacity of 4tb. This goes inside the machine (it connects to the SATA port) You may be able to attach an additional 2 USB drives externally - the documentation is not clear on this, and it's probably not a great idea to do so anyway.

The 4tb for each disk is probably badly written - most likely by someone who does not speak English as a first language and was modifying the specs from the 2 disk model in the photo or something like that.

Comment: Thank you. I've decided to buy the higher version instead.

Answer (score 1):

That particular model has only 1 SATA interface for the HDD so your only able to have 1 HDD upto the size of 4TB